# How can I make sure that pinning with apt-get is compatible with virtual packages?

Tags: apt, packaging, pinning

In order to allow php5.2 being used on lucid, I created a ppa ([ppa:txwikinger/php5.2](https://launchpad.net/~txwikinger/+archive/php5.2)) and build several php5.2 packages there. In order to prefer those packages I have given instructions to pin them. However, the packages php5-mcrypt and php5-imap do not correctly load due to the dependency to phpapi, even phpapi is provided by i.e. php5-cgi, php5-cli which are available. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. I made a mistake with the pinning conditions.

Edit:

The version of the pinning did not match what could be found or was missing for the package depending on the virtual package.

Comment: What exactly was the mistake? Posting more detail would make this question more useful to anyone who finds themselves in a similar situation.

Comment: The version of the pinning did not match what could be found or was missing for the package depending on the virtual package.